# Why are some shotgun mods "not recommended for slugs"?

Tags: battlefield-4

Specifically the modified and full choke mods have descriptions which call out that they are not recommended for use with slugs.  Is there a specific reason for this other than further narrowing the potential area that will impact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think that because full choke reduces the spread of shot it will not work with a slug, because a slug is a single round and has no spread. So you will not get any benefit.

The Battlelog description is

> Significantly tightens the shot spread for improved Accuracy, but has
>   penalities for Stability and Hip Fire as well. Not recommended with
>   Slugs.

So coupled with a slug, you would not get any benefit from the reduced spread, but you would incur a penalty to stability and hip fire.

> The Full Choke is a weapon attachment featured in Battlefield 4. It
>   tightens the spread of buckshot or flechettes. It improves the ADS
>   accuracy, significantly more than either no attachment, or the
>   Modified Choke. **As with any shotgun choke, it adds an increase to
>   recoil**.

[Referenced from Battlefield.wikia.com](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Full_Choke)

Comment: Interesting - so no negative effect, but no positive?

Comment: Well `battlefield.wikia.com` states that it increases recoil. So I guess that is a negative affect. So coupled with a slug, you'd only get extra recoil for no benefit.

REF: http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Full_Choke

Answer (score -1):

I would like to recommend you do not shoot non-rifled slug or sabot slugs through any kind of choke. those are designed for rifled bore shotguns that has no choke, forcing a solid slug through a choke will probably blow up your gun.

Comment: This might be true in real life, but does this also apply to the _video game_ we are talking about?